# Compiling a BIG matrix

Tags: matrices, paper-size

I have a large matrix (say, 100x100) in LaTeX code and I want to view it in a human-readable form. Obviously compiling the TeX code (of the matrix and nothing else) is the best way (much better than copying to a spreadsheet). However, simply compiling into an A4 page doesn't work - only a small portion of the matrix is seen.

So, is there a way around it? Maybe some definition of "infinite" paper size?

Comment: Even if you succeed in inserting an A3 or A2 sheet in the appropriate spot in the paper, or a "virtual" sheet of paper of essentially unbounded size, you need to ask yourself seriously what exactly you're trying to achieve by printing all 10,000 elements of the matrix on a single page. Might you be able to get by with displaying only a selected few entries -- say, those on the main diagonal or first off-diagonal? Does the matrix (or, possibly, its inverse) have some (relatively) simple structure, such as being band-diagonal? If so, it's probably much more important to highlight that structure.

Comment: how about `\usepackage[paperwidth=50in,paperheight=50in]{geometry}`

Comment: Have you though of using hyperlinks to ``zoom in'' to parts of the matrix? The `hyperref` package lets you do this.

Comment: "*I want to view it in a human-readable form.*" ... 

That's 10,000 values. ... Do you mean micro-readable (can look a value up) or macro-readable (can see the bigger picture)? ... Also, what does the matrix contain? How about generating a graphical heat-map (i.e., a bitmap)?

Comment: You can also have a big `.eps` picture of the matrix in a very high resolution and include in the `.pdf` file and some very patient reader will zoom the heck out of it to read the relevant parts. Sounds like a Cold-War tactic with microfilms. Or index the matrices *"from col 50/row 40 to ...."* and give it partially.

Comment: Can you say something about what's in the matrix? For example, if it's just zeros and ones than it's probably easier to show the matrix than if the entries are complex expressions.

Comment: badroit - I want micro-readable.
Marc - the entries are sums of variables. An entry can be quite long.

Everyone - I appreciate your suggestions about other ways of reading the matrix, but I know what I'm doing; I simply want to know how to do it.

Comment: @GadiA to notify people you need to use the `@` syntax (and can only do that for one user per comment). `\resizebox` (or is it `\rescalebox`?) from the graphicx package may help.

Answer (score 15):

You can have something very close to unlimited paper: Maximum papersize. The following example will output a pdf shrinked to the page size you need:

```
\documentclass[preview=true]{standalone}

\usepackage[paperwidth=\maxdimen,paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{50}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}
    2202 & 2229 & 2256 & 2283 & 2310 & 2337 & 2364 & 2391 & 2418 & 2445 & 2472 & 2499 & 1 & 28 & 55 & 82 & 109 & 136 & 163 & 190 & 217 & 244 & 271 & 298 & 325 & 1577 & 1604 & 1631 & 1658 & 1685 & 1712 & 1739 & 1766 & 1793 & 1820 & 1847 & 1874 & 1251 & 1278 & 680 & 707 & 734 & 761 & 788 & 815 & 842 & 869 & 896 & 923 & 950\\ 2228 & 2255 & 2282 & 2309 & 2336 & 2363 & 2390 & 2417 & 2444 & 2471 & 2498 & 1900 & 27 & 54 & 81 & 108 & 135 & 162 & 189 & 216 & 243 & 270 & 297 & 324 & 326 & 1603 & 1630 & 1657 & 1684 & 1711 & 1738 & 1765 & 1792 & 1819 & 1846 & 1873 & 1275 & 1277 & 1304 & 706 & 733 & 760 & 787 & 814 & 841 & 868 & 895 & 922 & 949 & 951\\ 2254 & 2281 & 2308 & 2335 & 2362 & 2389 & 2416 & 2443 & 2470 & 2497 & 1899 & 1901 & 53 & 80 & 107 & 134 & 161 & 188 & 215 & 242 & 269 & 296 & 323 & 350 & 352 & 1629 & 1656 & 1683 & 1710 & 1737 & 1764 & 1791 & 1818 & 1845 & 1872 & 1274 & 1276 & 1303 & 1330 & 732 & 759 & 786 & 813 & 840 & 867 & 894 & 921 & 948 & 975 & 977\\ 2280 & 2307 & 2334 & 2361 & 2388 & 2415 & 2442 & 2469 & 2496 & 1898 & 1925 & 1927 & 79 & 106 & 133 & 160 & 187 & 214 & 241 & 268 & 295 & 322 & 349 & 351 & 378 & 1655 & 1682 & 1709 & 1736 & 1763 & 1790 & 1817 & 1844 & 1871 & 1273 & 1300 & 1302 & 1329 & 1356 & 758 & 785 & 812 & 839 & 866 & 893 & 920 & 947 & 974 & 976 & 1003\\ 2306 & 2333 & 2360 & 2387 & 2414 & 2441 & 2468 & 2495 & 1897 & 1924 & 1926 & 1953 & 105 & 132 & 159 & 186 & 213 & 240 & 267 & 294 & 321 & 348 & 375 & 377 & 404 & 1681 & 1708 & 1735 & 1762 & 1789 & 1816 & 1843 & 1870 & 1272 & 1299 & 1301 & 1328 & 1355 & 1382 & 784 & 811 & 838 & 865 & 892 & 919 & 946 & 973 & 1000 & 1002 & 1029\\ 2332 & 2359 & 2386 & 2413 & 2440 & 2467 & 2494 & 1896 & 1923 & 1950 & 1952 & 1979 & 131 & 158 & 185 & 212 & 239 & 266 & 293 & 320 & 347 & 374 & 376 & 403 & 430 & 1707 & 1734 & 1761 & 1788 & 1815 & 1842 & 1869 & 1271 & 1298 & 1325 & 1327 & 1354 & 1381 & 1408 & 810 & 837 & 864 & 891 & 918 & 945 & 972 & 999 & 1001 & 1028 & 1055\\ 2358 & 2385 & 2412 & 2439 & 2466 & 2493 & 1895 & 1922 & 1949 & 1951 & 1978 & 2005 & 157 & 184 & 211 & 238 & 265 & 292 & 319 & 346 & 373 & 400 & 402 & 429 & 456 & 1733 & 1760 & 1787 & 1814 & 1841 & 1868 & 1270 & 1297 & 1324 & 1326 & 1353 & 1380 & 1407 & 1434 & 836 & 863 & 890 & 917 & 944 & 971 & 998 & 1025 & 1027 & 1054 & 1081\\ 2384 & 2411 & 2438 & 2465 & 2492 & 1894 & 1921 & 1948 & 1975 & 1977 & 2004 & 2031 & 183 & 210 & 237 & 264 & 291 & 318 & 345 & 372 & 399 & 401 & 428 & 455 & 482 & 1759 & 1786 & 1813 & 1840 & 1867 & 1269 & 1296 & 1323 & 1350 & 1352 & 1379 & 1406 & 1433 & 1460 & 862 & 889 & 916 & 943 & 970 & 997 & 1024 & 1026 & 1053 & 1080 & 1107\\ 2410 & 2437 & 2464 & 2491 & 1893 & 1920 & 1947 & 1974 & 1976 & 2003 & 2030 & 2057 & 209 & 236 & 263 & 290 & 317 & 344 & 371 & 398 & 425 & 427 & 454 & 481 & 508 & 1785 & 1812 & 1839 & 1866 & 1268 & 1295 & 1322 & 1349 & 1351 & 1378 & 1405 & 1432 & 1459 & 1486 & 888 & 915 & 942 & 969 & 996 & 1023 & 1050 & 1052 & 1079 & 1106 & 1133\\ 2436 & 2463 & 2490 & 1892 & 1919 & 1946 & 1973 & 2000 & 2002 & 2029 & 2056 & 2083 & 235 & 262 & 289 & 316 & 343 & 370 & 397 & 424 & 426 & 453 & 480 & 507 & 534 & 1811 & 1838 & 1865 & 1267 & 1294 & 1321 & 1348 & 1375 & 1377 & 1404 & 1431 & 1458 & 1485 & 1512 & 914 & 941 & 968 & 995 & 1022 & 1049 & 1051 & 1078 & 1105 & 1132 & 1159\\ 2462 & 2489 & 1891 & 1918 & 1945 & 1972 & 1999 & 2001 & 2028 & 2055 & 2082 & 2109 & 261 & 288 & 315 & 342 & 369 & 396 & 423 & 450 & 452 & 479 & 506 & 533 & 560 & 1837 & 1864 & 1266 & 1293 & 1320 & 1347 & 1374 & 1376 & 1403 & 1430 & 1457 & 1484 & 1511 & 1538 & 940 & 967 & 994 & 1021 & 1048 & 1075 & 1077 & 1104 & 1131 & 1158 & 1185\\ 2488 & 1890 & 1917 & 1944 & 1971 & 1998 & 2025 & 2027 & 2054 & 2081 & 2108 & 2135 & 287 & 314 & 341 & 368 & 395 & 422 & 449 & 451 & 478 & 505 & 532 & 559 & 586 & 1863 & 1265 & 1292 & 1319 & 1346 & 1373 & 1400 & 1402 & 1429 & 1456 & 1483 & 1510 & 1537 & 1564 & 966 & 993 & 1020 & 1047 & 1074 & 1076 & 1103 & 1130 & 1157 & 1184 & 1211\\ 14 & 1916 & 1943 & 1970 & 1997 & 2024 & 2026 & 2053 & 2080 & 2107 & 2134 & 2161 & 2188 & 340 & 367 & 394 & 421 & 448 & 475 & 477 & 504 & 531 & 558 & 585 & 612 & 1264 & 1291 & 1318 & 1345 & 1372 & 1399 & 1401 & 1428 & 1455 & 1482 & 1509 & 1536 & 1563 & 1590 & 992 & 1019 & 1046 & 1073 & 1100 & 1102 & 1129 & 1156 & 1183 & 1210 & 1237\\ 1915 & 1942 & 1969 & 1996 & 2023 & 2050 & 2052 & 2079 & 2106 & 2133 & 2160 & 2187 & 339 & 366 & 393 & 420 & 447 & 474 & 476 & 503 & 530 & 557 & 584 & 611 & 13 & 1290 & 1317 & 1344 & 1371 & 1398 & 1425 & 1427 & 1454 & 1481 & 1508 & 1535 & 1562 & 1589 & 1616 & 1018 & 1045 & 1072 & 1099 & 1101 & 1128 & 1155 & 1182 & 1209 & 1236 & 638\\ 1941 & 1968 & 1995 & 2022 & 2049 & 2051 & 2078 & 2105 & 2132 & 2159 & 2186 & 2213 & 365 & 392 & 419 & 446 & 473 & 500 & 502 & 529 & 556 & 583 & 610 & 12 & 39 & 1316 & 1343 & 1370 & 1397 & 1424 & 1426 & 1453 & 1480 & 1507 & 1534 & 1561 & 1588 & 1615 & 1642 & 1044 & 1071 & 1098 & 1125 & 1127 & 1154 & 1181 & 1208 & 1235 & 637 & 664\\ 1967 & 1994 & 2021 & 2048 & 2075 & 2077 & 2104 & 2131 & 2158 & 2185 & 2212 & 2239 & 391 & 418 & 445 & 472 & 499 & 501 & 528 & 555 & 582 & 609 & 11 & 38 & 65 & 1342 & 1369 & 1396 & 1423 & 1450 & 1452 & 1479 & 1506 & 1533 & 1560 & 1587 & 1614 & 1641 & 1668 & 1070 & 1097 & 1124 & 1126 & 1153 & 1180 & 1207 & 1234 & 636 & 663 & 690\\ 1993 & 2020 & 2047 & 2074 & 2076 & 2103 & 2130 & 2157 & 2184 & 2211 & 2238 & 2265 & 417 & 444 & 471 & 498 & 525 & 527 & 554 & 581 & 608 & 10 & 37 & 64 & 91 & 1368 & 1395 & 1422 & 1449 & 1451 & 1478 & 1505 & 1532 & 1559 & 1586 & 1613 & 1640 & 1667 & 1694 & 1096 & 1123 & 1150 & 1152 & 1179 & 1206 & 1233 & 635 & 662 & 689 & 716\\ 2019 & 2046 & 2073 & 2100 & 2102 & 2129 & 2156 & 2183 & 2210 & 2237 & 2264 & 2291 & 443 & 470 & 497 & 524 & 526 & 553 & 580 & 607 & 9 & 36 & 63 & 90 & 117 & 1394 & 1421 & 1448 & 1475 & 1477 & 1504 & 1531 & 1558 & 1585 & 1612 & 1639 & 1666 & 1693 & 1720 & 1122 & 1149 & 1151 & 1178 & 1205 & 1232 & 634 & 661 & 688 & 715 & 742\\ 2045 & 2072 & 2099 & 2101 & 2128 & 2155 & 2182 & 2209 & 2236 & 2263 & 2290 & 2317 & 469 & 496 & 523 & 550 & 552 & 579 & 606 & 8 & 35 & 62 & 89 & 116 & 143 & 1420 & 1447 & 1474 & 1476 & 1503 & 1530 & 1557 & 1584 & 1611 & 1638 & 1665 & 1692 & 1719 & 1746 & 1148 & 1175 & 1177 & 1204 & 1231 & 633 & 660 & 687 & 714 & 741 & 768\\ 2071 & 2098 & 2125 & 2127 & 2154 & 2181 & 2208 & 2235 & 2262 & 2289 & 2316 & 2343 & 495 & 522 & 549 & 551 & 578 & 605 & 7 & 34 & 61 & 88 & 115 & 142 & 169 & 1446 & 1473 & 1500 & 1502 & 1529 & 1556 & 1583 & 1610 & 1637 & 1664 & 1691 & 1718 & 1745 & 1772 & 1174 & 1176 & 1203 & 1230 & 632 & 659 & 686 & 713 & 740 & 767 & 794\\ 2097 & 2124 & 2126 & 2153 & 2180 & 2207 & 2234 & 2261 & 2288 & 2315 & 2342 & 2369 & 521 & 548 & 575 & 577 & 604 & 6 & 33 & 60 & 87 & 114 & 141 & 168 & 195 & 1472 & 1499 & 1501 & 1528 & 1555 & 1582 & 1609 & 1636 & 1663 & 1690 & 1717 & 1744 & 1771 & 1798 & 1200 & 1202 & 1229 & 631 & 658 & 685 & 712 & 739 & 766 & 793 & 820\\ 2123 & 2150 & 2152 & 2179 & 2206 & 2233 & 2260 & 2287 & 2314 & 2341 & 2368 & 2395 & 547 & 574 & 576 & 603 & 5 & 32 & 59 & 86 & 113 & 140 & 167 & 194 & 221 & 1498 & 1525 & 1527 & 1554 & 1581 & 1608 & 1635 & 1662 & 1689 & 1716 & 1743 & 1770 & 1797 & 1824 & 1201 & 1228 & 630 & 657 & 684 & 711 & 738 & 765 & 792 & 819 & 846\\ 2149 & 2151 & 2178 & 2205 & 2232 & 2259 & 2286 & 2313 & 2340 & 2367 & 2394 & 2421 & 573 & 600 & 602 & 4 & 31 & 58 & 85 & 112 & 139 & 166 & 193 & 220 & 247 & 1524 & 1526 & 1553 & 1580 & 1607 & 1634 & 1661 & 1688 & 1715 & 1742 & 1769 & 1796 & 1823 & 1850 & 1227 & 629 & 656 & 683 & 710 & 737 & 764 & 791 & 818 & 845 & 872\\ 2175 & 2177 & 2204 & 2231 & 2258 & 2285 & 2312 & 2339 & 2366 & 2393 & 2420 & 2447 & 599 & 601 & 3 & 30 & 57 & 84 & 111 & 138 & 165 & 192 & 219 & 246 & 273 & 1550 & 1552 & 1579 & 1606 & 1633 & 1660 & 1687 & 1714 & 1741 & 1768 & 1795 & 1822 & 1849 & 1851 & 628 & 655 & 682 & 709 & 736 & 763 & 790 & 817 & 844 & 871 & 898\\ 2176 & 2203 & 2230 & 2257 & 2284 & 2311 & 2338 & 2365 & 2392 & 2419 & 2446 & 2473 & 625 & 2 & 29 & 56 & 83 & 110 & 137 & 164 & 191 & 218 & 245 & 272 & 299 & 1551 & 1578 & 1605 & 1632 & 1659 & 1686 & 1713 & 1740 & 1767 & 1794 & 1821 & 1848 & 1875 & 1252 & 654 & 681 & 708 & 735 & 762 & 789 & 816 & 843 & 870 & 897 & 924\\ 327 & 354 & 381 & 408 & 435 & 462 & 489 & 516 & 543 & 570 & 597 & 624 & 1876 & 1903 & 1930 & 1957 & 1984 & 2011 & 2038 & 2065 & 2092 & 2119 & 2146 & 2173 & 2200 & 952 & 979 & 1006 & 1033 & 1060 & 1087 & 1114 & 1141 & 1168 & 1195 & 1222 & 1249 & 626 & 653 & 1305 & 1332 & 1359 & 1386 & 1413 & 1440 & 1467 & 1494 & 1521 & 1548 & 1575\\ 353 & 380 & 407 & 434 & 461 & 488 & 515 & 542 & 569 & 596 & 623 & 25 & 1902 & 1929 & 1956 & 1983 & 2010 & 2037 & 2064 & 2091 & 2118 & 2145 & 2172 & 2199 & 2201 & 978 & 1005 & 1032 & 1059 & 1086 & 1113 & 1140 & 1167 & 1194 & 1221 & 1248 & 650 & 652 & 679 & 1331 & 1358 & 1385 & 1412 & 1439 & 1466 & 1493 & 1520 & 1547 & 1574 & 1576\\ 379 & 406 & 433 & 460 & 487 & 514 & 541 & 568 & 595 & 622 & 24 & 26 & 1928 & 1955 & 1982 & 2009 & 2036 & 2063 & 2090 & 2117 & 2144 & 2171 & 2198 & 2225 & 2227 & 1004 & 1031 & 1058 & 1085 & 1112 & 1139 & 1166 & 1193 & 1220 & 1247 & 649 & 651 & 678 & 705 & 1357 & 1384 & 1411 & 1438 & 1465 & 1492 & 1519 & 1546 & 1573 & 1600 & 1602\\ 405 & 432 & 459 & 486 & 513 & 540 & 567 & 594 & 621 & 23 & 50 & 52 & 1954 & 1981 & 2008 & 2035 & 2062 & 2089 & 2116 & 2143 & 2170 & 2197 & 2224 & 2226 & 2253 & 1030 & 1057 & 1084 & 1111 & 1138 & 1165 & 1192 & 1219 & 1246 & 648 & 675 & 677 & 704 & 731 & 1383 & 1410 & 1437 & 1464 & 1491 & 1518 & 1545 & 1572 & 1599 & 1601 & 1628\\ 431 & 458 & 485 & 512 & 539 & 566 & 593 & 620 & 22 & 49 & 51 & 78 & 1980 & 2007 & 2034 & 2061 & 2088 & 2115 & 2142 & 2169 & 2196 & 2223 & 2250 & 2252 & 2279 & 1056 & 1083 & 1110 & 1137 & 1164 & 1191 & 1218 & 1245 & 647 & 674 & 676 & 703 & 730 & 757 & 1409 & 1436 & 1463 & 1490 & 1517 & 1544 & 1571 & 1598 & 1625 & 1627 & 1654\\ 457 & 484 & 511 & 538 & 565 & 592 & 619 & 21 & 48 & 75 & 77 & 104 & 2006 & 2033 & 2060 & 2087 & 2114 & 2141 & 2168 & 2195 & 2222 & 2249 & 2251 & 2278 & 2305 & 1082 & 1109 & 1136 & 1163 & 1190 & 1217 & 1244 & 646 & 673 & 700 & 702 & 729 & 756 & 783 & 1435 & 1462 & 1489 & 1516 & 1543 & 1570 & 1597 & 1624 & 1626 & 1653 & 1680\\ 483 & 510 & 537 & 564 & 591 & 618 & 20 & 47 & 74 & 76 & 103 & 130 & 2032 & 2059 & 2086 & 2113 & 2140 & 2167 & 2194 & 2221 & 2248 & 2275 & 2277 & 2304 & 2331 & 1108 & 1135 & 1162 & 1189 & 1216 & 1243 & 645 & 672 & 699 & 701 & 728 & 755 & 782 & 809 & 1461 & 1488 & 1515 & 1542 & 1569 & 1596 & 1623 & 1650 & 1652 & 1679 & 1706\\ 509 & 536 & 563 & 590 & 617 & 19 & 46 & 73 & 100 & 102 & 129 & 156 & 2058 & 2085 & 2112 & 2139 & 2166 & 2193 & 2220 & 2247 & 2274 & 2276 & 2303 & 2330 & 2357 & 1134 & 1161 & 1188 & 1215 & 1242 & 644 & 671 & 698 & 725 & 727 & 754 & 781 & 808 & 835 & 1487 & 1514 & 1541 & 1568 & 1595 & 1622 & 1649 & 1651 & 1678 & 1705 & 1732\\ 535 & 562 & 589 & 616 & 18 & 45 & 72 & 99 & 101 & 128 & 155 & 182 & 2084 & 2111 & 2138 & 2165 & 2192 & 2219 & 2246 & 2273 & 2300 & 2302 & 2329 & 2356 & 2383 & 1160 & 1187 & 1214 & 1241 & 643 & 670 & 697 & 724 & 726 & 753 & 780 & 807 & 834 & 861 & 1513 & 1540 & 1567 & 1594 & 1621 & 1648 & 1675 & 1677 & 1704 & 1731 & 1758\\ 561 & 588 & 615 & 17 & 44 & 71 & 98 & 125 & 127 & 154 & 181 & 208 & 2110 & 2137 & 2164 & 2191 & 2218 & 2245 & 2272 & 2299 & 2301 & 2328 & 2355 & 2382 & 2409 & 1186 & 1213 & 1240 & 642 & 669 & 696 & 723 & 750 & 752 & 779 & 806 & 833 & 860 & 887 & 1539 & 1566 & 1593 & 1620 & 1647 & 1674 & 1676 & 1703 & 1730 & 1757 & 1784\\ 587 & 614 & 16 & 43 & 70 & 97 & 124 & 126 & 153 & 180 & 207 & 234 & 2136 & 2163 & 2190 & 2217 & 2244 & 2271 & 2298 & 2325 & 2327 & 2354 & 2381 & 2408 & 2435 & 1212 & 1239 & 641 & 668 & 695 & 722 & 749 & 751 & 778 & 805 & 832 & 859 & 886 & 913 & 1565 & 1592 & 1619 & 1646 & 1673 & 1700 & 1702 & 1729 & 1756 & 1783 & 1810\\ 613 & 15 & 42 & 69 & 96 & 123 & 150 & 152 & 179 & 206 & 233 & 260 & 2162 & 2189 & 2216 & 2243 & 2270 & 2297 & 2324 & 2326 & 2353 & 2380 & 2407 & 2434 & 2461 & 1238 & 640 & 667 & 694 & 721 & 748 & 775 & 777 & 804 & 831 & 858 & 885 & 912 & 939 & 1591 & 1618 & 1645 & 1672 & 1699 & 1701 & 1728 & 1755 & 1782 & 1809 & 1836\\ 1889 & 41 & 68 & 95 & 122 & 149 & 151 & 178 & 205 & 232 & 259 & 286 & 313 & 2215 & 2242 & 2269 & 2296 & 2323 & 2350 & 2352 & 2379 & 2406 & 2433 & 2460 & 2487 & 639 & 666 & 693 & 720 & 747 & 774 & 776 & 803 & 830 & 857 & 884 & 911 & 938 & 965 & 1617 & 1644 & 1671 & 1698 & 1725 & 1727 & 1754 & 1781 & 1808 & 1835 & 1862\\ 40 & 67 & 94 & 121 & 148 & 175 & 177 & 204 & 231 & 258 & 285 & 312 & 2214 & 2241 & 2268 & 2295 & 2322 & 2349 & 2351 & 2378 & 2405 & 2432 & 2459 & 2486 & 1888 & 665 & 692 & 719 & 746 & 773 & 800 & 802 & 829 & 856 & 883 & 910 & 937 & 964 & 991 & 1643 & 1670 & 1697 & 1724 & 1726 & 1753 & 1780 & 1807 & 1834 & 1861 & 1263\\ 66 & 93 & 120 & 147 & 174 & 176 & 203 & 230 & 257 & 284 & 311 & 338 & 2240 & 2267 & 2294 & 2321 & 2348 & 2375 & 2377 & 2404 & 2431 & 2458 & 2485 & 1887 & 1914 & 691 & 718 & 745 & 772 & 799 & 801 & 828 & 855 & 882 & 909 & 936 & 963 & 990 & 1017 & 1669 & 1696 & 1723 & 1750 & 1752 & 1779 & 1806 & 1833 & 1860 & 1262 & 1289\\ 92 & 119 & 146 & 173 & 200 & 202 & 229 & 256 & 283 & 310 & 337 & 364 & 2266 & 2293 & 2320 & 2347 & 2374 & 2376 & 2403 & 2430 & 2457 & 2484 & 1886 & 1913 & 1940 & 717 & 744 & 771 & 798 & 825 & 827 & 854 & 881 & 908 & 935 & 962 & 989 & 1016 & 1043 & 1695 & 1722 & 1749 & 1751 & 1778 & 1805 & 1832 & 1859 & 1261 & 1288 & 1315\\ 118 & 145 & 172 & 199 & 201 & 228 & 255 & 282 & 309 & 336 & 363 & 390 & 2292 & 2319 & 2346 & 2373 & 2400 & 2402 & 2429 & 2456 & 2483 & 1885 & 1912 & 1939 & 1966 & 743 & 770 & 797 & 824 & 826 & 853 & 880 & 907 & 934 & 961 & 988 & 1015 & 1042 & 1069 & 1721 & 1748 & 1775 & 1777 & 1804 & 1831 & 1858 & 1260 & 1287 & 1314 & 1341\\ 144 & 171 & 198 & 225 & 227 & 254 & 281 & 308 & 335 & 362 & 389 & 416 & 2318 & 2345 & 2372 & 2399 & 2401 & 2428 & 2455 & 2482 & 1884 & 1911 & 1938 & 1965 & 1992 & 769 & 796 & 823 & 850 & 852 & 879 & 906 & 933 & 960 & 987 & 1014 & 1041 & 1068 & 1095 & 1747 & 1774 & 1776 & 1803 & 1830 & 1857 & 1259 & 1286 & 1313 & 1340 & 1367\\ 170 & 197 & 224 & 226 & 253 & 280 & 307 & 334 & 361 & 388 & 415 & 442 & 2344 & 2371 & 2398 & 2425 & 2427 & 2454 & 2481 & 1883 & 1910 & 1937 & 1964 & 1991 & 2018 & 795 & 822 & 849 & 851 & 878 & 905 & 932 & 959 & 986 & 1013 & 1040 & 1067 & 1094 & 1121 & 1773 & 1800 & 1802 & 1829 & 1856 & 1258 & 1285 & 1312 & 1339 & 1366 & 1393\\ 196 & 223 & 250 & 252 & 279 & 306 & 333 & 360 & 387 & 414 & 441 & 468 & 2370 & 2397 & 2424 & 2426 & 2453 & 2480 & 1882 & 1909 & 1936 & 1963 & 1990 & 2017 & 2044 & 821 & 848 & 875 & 877 & 904 & 931 & 958 & 985 & 1012 & 1039 & 1066 & 1093 & 1120 & 1147 & 1799 & 1801 & 1828 & 1855 & 1257 & 1284 & 1311 & 1338 & 1365 & 1392 & 1419\\ 222 & 249 & 251 & 278 & 305 & 332 & 359 & 386 & 413 & 440 & 467 & 494 & 2396 & 2423 & 2450 & 2452 & 2479 & 1881 & 1908 & 1935 & 1962 & 1989 & 2016 & 2043 & 2070 & 847 & 874 & 876 & 903 & 930 & 957 & 984 & 1011 & 1038 & 1065 & 1092 & 1119 & 1146 & 1173 & 1825 & 1827 & 1854 & 1256 & 1283 & 1310 & 1337 & 1364 & 1391 & 1418 & 1445\\ 248 & 275 & 277 & 304 & 331 & 358 & 385 & 412 & 439 & 466 & 493 & 520 & 2422 & 2449 & 2451 & 2478 & 1880 & 1907 & 1934 & 1961 & 1988 & 2015 & 2042 & 2069 & 2096 & 873 & 900 & 902 & 929 & 956 & 983 & 1010 & 1037 & 1064 & 1091 & 1118 & 1145 & 1172 & 1199 & 1826 & 1853 & 1255 & 1282 & 1309 & 1336 & 1363 & 1390 & 1417 & 1444 & 1471\\ 274 & 276 & 303 & 330 & 357 & 384 & 411 & 438 & 465 & 492 & 519 & 546 & 2448 & 2475 & 2477 & 1879 & 1906 & 1933 & 1960 & 1987 & 2014 & 2041 & 2068 & 2095 & 2122 & 899 & 901 & 928 & 955 & 982 & 1009 & 1036 & 1063 & 1090 & 1117 & 1144 & 1171 & 1198 & 1225 & 1852 & 1254 & 1281 & 1308 & 1335 & 1362 & 1389 & 1416 & 1443 & 1470 & 1497\\ 300 & 302 & 329 & 356 & 383 & 410 & 437 & 464 & 491 & 518 & 545 & 572 & 2474 & 2476 & 1878 & 1905 & 1932 & 1959 & 1986 & 2013 & 2040 & 2067 & 2094 & 2121 & 2148 & 925 & 927 & 954 & 981 & 1008 & 1035 & 1062 & 1089 & 1116 & 1143 & 1170 & 1197 & 1224 & 1226 & 1253 & 1280 & 1307 & 1334 & 1361 & 1388 & 1415 & 1442 & 1469 & 1496 & 1523\\ 301 & 328 & 355 & 382 & 409 & 436 & 463 & 490 & 517 & 544 & 571 & 598 & 2500 & 1877 & 1904 & 1931 & 1958 & 1985 & 2012 & 2039 & 2066 & 2093 & 2120 & 2147 & 2174 & 926 & 953 & 980 & 1007 & 1034 & 1061 & 1088 & 1115 & 1142 & 1169 & 1196 & 1223 & 1250 & 627 & 1279 & 1306 & 1333 & 1360 & 1387 & 1414 & 1441 & 1468 & 1495 & 1522 & 1549
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

just change `MaxMatrixCols` to the value you need. result is (click on image for larger image):

[image: result]

**Old Method:**
I would select some papersize like A3 (or manually specify with `paperwidth=50in,paperheight=50in` as suggested)and than rescale the matrix. because pdf is a vector based file format, you can simply zoom in or print at bigger sheet of paper. I have a MWE with a 50x50 Matrix here:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage[landscape,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\myx}
\newlength{\myy}

\newcommand{\resizetopage}[1]{%
    \settowidth{\myx}{#1}%
    \settototalheight{\myy}{#1}%
    \ifdimcomp{\myx}{<}{\myy}{%
        \resizebox*{!}{\textheight}{#1}}{%
        \resizebox*{\textwidth}{!}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\pagematrix}[1]{
        \resizetopage{%
            $\begin{pmatrix}%
            #1%
            \end{pmatrix}$%
        }}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{50}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \pagematrix{
    2202 & 2229 & 2256 & 2283 & 2310 & 2337 & 2364 & 2391 & 2418 & 2445 & 2472 & 2499 & 1 & 28 & 55 & 82 & 109 & 136 & 163 & 190 & 217 & 244 & 271 & 298 & 325 & 1577 & 1604 & 1631 & 1658 & 1685 & 1712 & 1739 & 1766 & 1793 & 1820 & 1847 & 1874 & 1251 & 1278 & 680 & 707 & 734 & 761 & 788 & 815 & 842 & 869 & 896 & 923 & 950\\ 2228 & 2255 & 2282 & 2309 & 2336 & 2363 & 2390 & 2417 & 2444 & 2471 & 2498 & 1900 & 27 & 54 & 81 & 108 & 135 & 162 & 189 & 216 & 243 & 270 & 297 & 324 & 326 & 1603 & 1630 & 1657 & 1684 & 1711 & 1738 & 1765 & 1792 & 1819 & 1846 & 1873 & 1275 & 1277 & 1304 & 706 & 733 & 760 & 787 & 814 & 841 & 868 & 895 & 922 & 949 & 951\\ 2254 & sory I had to cut because of stackexchange...}

\end{document}
```

remember to set the `MaxMatrixCols` counter to your needs.